# Angular 4 is loading default component on clicking anchor tag that is pointing to other component only for first time

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, lazy-loading, bootstrapping

Angular 4 is loading default component on clicking anchor tag that is pointing to other component only for first time.

This happens only when chunk/bundle js of other component is not loaded.

Issue get fixed by adding preload: true in routes.

`{
   path: 'aps',
   loadChildren: './aps/aps.module#ApsModule',
   data: { preload: true}
 }`

Is there any other way to fix the issue without doing a preload.

**Edit:** 
Further on investigation found that issue is only when resolver is present in route

`{
   path: 'summary/:apId',
   component: apsDetailsComponent,
   resolve: {
       data: apsSummaryResolver
   }
 }`

If resolver is removed it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will solve your problem but it works for me to load the children component having a route of /json/attribute (loads Attribute Component inside the JsonComponent), but you can try this and see if it works:

```
{
    path: 'json', 
    component: JsonComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '', 
            redirectTo: 'attribute',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: 'attribute',
            component: AttributeComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'edit',
            component: EditComponent
        }
    ],           
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
},
```

you also have to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in JsonComponent's html file.